# Extract a specific texts from multiple json files

Tags: powershell, cmd

So I am trying to extract a specific line from multiple json files and create a txt file and add these extracted line into this txt file

Here is each json File Looks like

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "mm-sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key_id": "01xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADAh\nk9P8vIQogdfdIxxxxxxx/9Fq\nwxeBX5Wk+CRXvklQQP37TDM=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "mm-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqr.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/mm-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqr.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Each and every json Files are having this pattern

What I am interested is in this line `"client_email": "mm-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqr.iam.gserviceaccount.com",`

I just need the email from that line, ie in this case `mm-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqr.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

I am trying to achieve this in Powershell

I tried the solution below

```
(Select-String -Path *json -Pattern 'client_email').Line | Set-Content AllSAEmails.txt
```

This created a txt file with the following pattern

```
  "client_email": "mm-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqr.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_email": "mm-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyas.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_email": "mm-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzae.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_email": "mm-qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqquh.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

But what I am interested is as below,is it possible to create a txt file with that pattern?

So since I have multiple jsons..each of the jsons has such an email..i would like to have all those emails inside a txt file seperated by comma

```
mm-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqr.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
mm-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyas.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
mm-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzae.iam.gserviceaccount.com,
mm-qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqquh.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ConvertFrom-Json` to parse the file, then the rest becomes trivial:

```
$emails = Get-ChildItem .\*.json |Get-Content -Raw |ConvertFrom-Json |Select -ExpandProperty client_email
```

If you want to output the emails to file and insert a line break every 10 lines, you could do something like:

```
@(
  for($i = 0;$i -lt $email.Length ;$i += 10){
    # output 10 emails and a blank string
    $emails[$i..($i + 9)]
    ""
  }
) |Set-Content .\path\to\file
```

Comment: Thats just awesome..i tested this and it worked well..i have a small request as well..can i add a blank line after every 10 lines..is it possible to add that as well to the same command above

Thanks @Mathias R. Jessen

Comment: You mean if you output `$emails` to a file afterwards, you want a line break for every 10?

Comment: yes exactly
`$emails = Get-ChildItem .\*.json |Get-Content -Raw |ConvertFrom-Json |Select -ExpandProperty client_email >>emails.txt`
I used this to create a file